# EPSG:4038 Gridset does not work with caching on GeoServer 2.2

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to setup a cache for a GeoTIFF base layer. I set it up and I went to the built in GeoWebCache page where it generates test map for the caching. I saw the built in projection
- EPSG:900913
- EPSG:4326

I tried these two links and it shows open layers map and it generates cached tiles properly. So I set to work to create a gridset for ESPG:4038 using this manual: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/tilecache/gridsets.html#webadmin-tilecaching-gridsets (I added 20 levels of zoom)

I added this gridset to the base map layer cache and now I see these three items in the GeoWebCache page.

- EPSG:900913
- EPSG:4326
- ESPG:4038

I tried the first two links and it works properly (showing the maps and I see the indicators that certain amount of disk space are being used by the cache layer). But when I try to open ESPG:4038, the generated OpenLayers preview map is blank and there's no activity in the disk space indicator for the cache. When I check on Google Chrome, it return 256x256 transparent png tiles.

I'd appreciate if anyone can point out which part I do wrong

Comment: GeoServer 2.2 is around six years old and is unsupported, I would suggest to try out with 2.13.1 first (latest stable)